# Ploting the Lasso L1 constraint

Tags: r, linear-regression, absolute-value

In Lasso regression the L1 constraint is used: [image]

I'm trying to plot the constraint using R. An example looks like: 
[image]

Here is the simple R code I wrote:

```
beta= seq(-1, 1, length=100)
lambda=2
penalty=lambda*abs(beta)
plot(penalty, type="l")
```

It draws only the lower part of the plot. How could I plot the upper part too in one plot?
Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: You're misunderstanding that plot. It's showing the equation abs(b1) + abs(b2) < 1

Comment: if you just want to plot, you could use `polygon`, then you just need to pass the four corner coords

Comment: @Ryan thank you, should then b1 be just an element of the vector B or a vector itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot `abs(b1) + abs(b2) = 1` you can plot `b2 = 1 - abs(b1)` and the negative of that (since the `abs` means either is a solution)

```
b1 <- seq(-1, 1, .01)
b2 <- 1 - abs(b1)
plot(b1, b2, ylim = c(-1, 1), type = 'l')
b2 <- -b2
lines(b1, b2)
```

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what I was trying to plot